# Why is the default choice for -I argument '{}'?

Tags: history, xargs

It seems you can pass in a variable name like 'file' for -I argument of `xargs`, but there are a plethora of examples that use {}. Is this because of the backward compatibility? Or does it help with the visibility of the variable location? Why many people use {} instead of a variable name?

Comment: I prefer `-IXXX` which makes it a pretty obvious placeholder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[A long time ago](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/1/find), `find … -exec …` used `{}` as the string to be replaced by the name of the matched file. This string was presumably chosen because it does not normally occur in a file name or otherwise in a command line.

At the time, `xargs` didn't even exist. When it was invented, it used `{}` too. When the `-i` option was added (I don't know who did it first: Solaris, presumably, given the time frame), it meant [“insert mode”](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xargs&sektion=1&manpath=SunOS+4.1.3); the default string to replace remained `{}`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that's just to be consistent with `find -exec` clause which introduced this curly braces convention.